# Getting error while running docker image: chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, fastapi

I have build a web scraper using selenium 4.16.0 and BeautifulSoup and using chrome driver. I am able to successfull create the docker image and run it. Once i click the url of my application, it throws the error

#### Docker File

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
# RUN apt-get update
# RUN apt-get install -y python3.10 
# RUN apt-get install -y python3.10-distutils
# RUN apt-get install -y pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

#### Python code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from utils import logger


class Parse_html:
    def __init__(self, retries: int = 3, timeout: int = 3):
        self.retries = retries
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.logger = logger.Logger()
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.service = webdriver.ChromeService(
            executable_path="chromedriver/chrome-headless-shell"
        )
        self.options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
        self.options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        self.options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        self.options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        self.options.add_argument(
            "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.1000.0 Safari/537.36"
        )
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
        self.driver.get("https://www.python.org/")

    async def get_text(
        self, url: str, decompose_tag_list: list = ["script", "style", "a", "img"]
    ):
        print(self.driver.title)
        for n in range(self.retries):
            await self.logger.info(__name__, f"extract text from {url}")
            self.driver.get(url)
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(self.timeout)
            soup = bs(self.driver.page_source, "html.parser")
            for tag in soup(decompose_tag_list):
                tag.decompose()
            self.driver.close()
            return re.sub(r"\n+|\s+", " ", soup.body.get_text(strip=True))

    async def get_metadata(
        self,
        url: str,
        attribute_list: list = ["name", "description"],
        filter_list: list = [
            "description",
            "og:title",
            "og:description",
            "og:type",
            "keywords",
        ],
    ):
        for n in range(self.retries):
            await self.logger.info(__name__, f"extract metadata from {url}")
            print(urlparse(url)[2])
            metadata_list = []
            self.driver.get(url)
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(self.timeout)
            soup = bs(self.driver.page_source, "html.parser")
            if soup.title:
                metadata_list.append(("title", "title", soup.title.string))
            for tag in soup.find_all("meta"):
                for attribute in attribute_list:
                    if attribute in tag.attrs:
                        if tag[attribute] in filter_list:
                            metadata_list.append(
                                ("meta", tag[attribute], tag["content"])
                            )
            self.driver.close()
            return metadata_list
```

#### requirements.txt

```
annotated-types==0.6.0
anyio==3.7.1
argcomplete==1.10.3
asgiref==3.7.2
attrs==23.1.0
backoff==2.2.1
bcrypt==4.1.2
beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
CacheControl==0.13.1
cachetools==5.3.2
certifi==2023.11.17
cffi==1.16.0
chardet==3.0.4
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
chroma-hnswlib==0.7.3
chromadb==0.4.21
click==8.1.7
coloredlogs==15.0.1
compressed-rtf==1.0.6
cryptography==41.0.7
Deprecated==1.2.14
distro==1.9.0
docx2txt==0.8
ebcdic==1.1.1
exceptiongroup==1.2.0
extract-msg==0.28.7
fastapi==0.105.0
filelock==3.13.1
firebase-admin==6.3.0
flatbuffers==23.5.26
fsspec==2023.12.2
google-api-core==2.15.0
google-api-python-client==2.111.0
google-auth==2.25.2
google-auth-httplib2==0.2.0
google-cloud-core==2.4.1
google-cloud-firestore==2.14.0
google-cloud-storage==2.14.0
google-crc32c==1.5.0
google-resumable-media==2.7.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.62.0
grpcio==1.60.0
grpcio-status==1.60.0
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==1.0.2
httplib2==0.22.0
httptools==0.6.1
httpx==0.26.0
huggingface-hub==0.20.1
humanfriendly==10.0
idna==3.6
IMAPClient==2.1.0
importlib-metadata==6.11.0
importlib-resources==6.1.1
kubernetes==28.1.0
lxml==4.9.4
mmh3==4.0.1
monotonic==1.6
mpmath==1.3.0
msgpack==1.0.7
numpy==1.26.2
oauthlib==3.2.2
olefile==0.47
onnxruntime==1.16.3
openai==1.6.1
opentelemetry-api==1.22.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-common==1.22.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-grpc==1.22.0
opentelemetry-instrumentation==0.43b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-asgi==0.43b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-fastapi==0.43b0
opentelemetry-proto==1.22.0
opentelemetry-sdk==1.22.0
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions==0.43b0
opentelemetry-util-http==0.43b0
outcome==1.3.0.post0
overrides==7.4.0
packaging==23.2
pdfminer.six==20191110
Pillow==10.1.0
posthog==3.1.0
proto-plus==1.23.0
protobuf==4.25.1
pulsar-client==3.3.0
pyasn1==0.5.1
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
pycparser==2.21
pycryptodome==3.19.0
pydantic==2.5.3
pydantic_core==2.14.6
PyJWT==2.8.0
pyparsing==3.1.1
PyPika==0.48.9
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python-pptx==0.6.23
PyYAML==6.0.1
regex==2023.12.25
requests==2.31.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.9
selenium==4.16.0
six==1.12.0
sniffio==1.3.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.5
SpeechRecognition==3.8.1
starlette==0.27.0
sympy==1.12
tenacity==8.2.3
textract==1.6.5
tiktoken==0.5.2
tokenizers==0.15.0
tqdm==4.66.1
trio==0.23.2
trio-websocket==0.11.1
typer==0.9.0
typing_extensions==4.9.0
tzlocal==5.2
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.18
uvicorn==0.25.0
uvloop==0.19.0
watchfiles==0.21.0
websocket-client==1.7.0
websockets==12.0
wrapt==1.16.0
wsproto==1.2.0
xlrd==1.2.0
XlsxWriter==3.1.9
zipp==3.17.0
```

#### Log

```
2023-12-26 00:31:07 INFO:     Started server process [1]
2023-12-26 00:31:07 INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
2023-12-26 00:31:07 INFO:     Application startup complete.
2023-12-26 00:31:07 INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2023-12-26 00:39:27 INFO:     192.168.65.1:56483 - "GET /en HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
2023-12-26 00:39:27 ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
2023-12-26 00:39:27 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 426, in run_asgi
2023-12-26 00:39:27     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1106, in __call__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     raise exc
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     raise exc
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     raise e
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
2023-12-26 00:39:27     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
2023-12-26 00:39:27     response = await func(request)
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 274, in app
2023-12-26 00:39:27     raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 191, in run_endpoint_function
2023-12-26 00:39:27     return await dependant.call(**values)
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/router/website_router.py", line 18, in get_page_by_name
2023-12-26 00:39:27     return await Website_controller().get_page_by_name(request, language_code)
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/controller/website_controller.py", line 10, in __init__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     self.country_detail_service = country_detail_service.Country_detail_service()
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/service/country_detail_service.py", line 14, in __init__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     self.process_service = process_service.Process_Service()
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/service/process_service.py", line 11, in __init__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     self.parse_html = Parse_html()
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/parsers/parse_html.py", line 25, in __init__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     super().__init__(
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
2023-12-26 00:39:27     self.service.start()
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
2023-12-26 00:39:27     self.assert_process_still_running()
2023-12-26 00:39:27   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
2023-12-26 00:39:27     raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
2023-12-26 00:39:27 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
Additional Notes
```

1. I have tried to download the binary from ([Chrome Binary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jMfe.png)) and manually entered the path to selenium chromer service and got the same error
2. I have enabled "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon" in docker desktop and still the same error
3. In the terminal I have tried to check chrome driver version with following commands but get

   ```
   /bin/sh: 33: chromeDrver: not found
   ```

   1. comand-a => `chromeDriver -v`
   2. comand-b => `chromeDriver --version`
4. The app runs perfectly fine when I comment out the above python code.
5. My application is working as expected in local
6. Its is a fast api application and uses uvicorn

I want to build the docker image in which the chrome driver runs and deploy it to google cloud run.

Answer (score 0):

The Selenium do not support to linux/arm64:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/#alternative-architectures

You could manually install chromium+chromedriver:

```
apt install chromium
```

Download chromedriver from:
https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v21.2.0/chromedriver-v21.2.0-linux-arm64.zip

Install dependencies for chromedriver:

```
apt install libglib2.0-0 libnss3 libxcb1
```